# Maintain same session in spring controller

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

I have two controller UserSignInController and PageNavigationController.I want to maintain same HttpSession in both the controller but I found a diff session in diff page.I have also added @SessionAttributes("userDetails") in controller page.please advice me how i create this?

UserSignInController

```
@RequestMapping(value="/analyzeinternet1.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSocialMediaAdmin(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        LOG.info(" session..." + session);
        ModelAndView mv = null;

        UserProfile up = (UserProfile) session.getAttribute("userDetails");
        if(up == null) { //Checking whether the user is already signed up or not. If not, the user is redirected to login page. 
            LOG.info("No user in session...");
            mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/login.html");
        } else {
            LOG.info("User in session..." + up);
            mv = new ModelAndView("internetanalyze");
            model.addAttribute("userDetails", up);
            session.setAttribute("userDetails", up);
            mv.addObject("clientId", up.getUserId());
        }

        LOG.info(mv);
        return mv;
    }
```

PageNavigationController

```
@RequestMapping(value="/analyzeinternet.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAnalyzeInternet(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        LOG.info("-----session..." + session);
        //LOG.info("-----userprofile..." + userDetails);
        ModelAndView mv = null;
         up = (UserProfile) session.getAttribute("userDetails");
            LOG.info("User in session..." + up);
            mv = new ModelAndView("internetanalyze");
            //mv.addObject("clientId", up.getUserId());
            return mv;
    }
```

both session id is different and my redirection code is

```
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/analyzeinternet.html">
```

Comment: Would you please tell me what the different that you found? As I know that all the controllers are singleton, so there is no problem that session crosses controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you browse your app from one page to second page and second page uses PageNavigationController where you do not get the same session? How are you checking if its not the same session? Are you sure you setting the userDetails in the session?

Also check if the session cookie is passed properly in the request. You can use firebug or chrome console to check the cookie value in the response and the request header.

Comment: I have print session and it gets diff value.yeh I have set userprofiles in session

Comment: please debug about the session cookie as well and confirm

Comment: it gives diff session id in console

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. This code is written in context.xml

```
<Context path="/sm" docBase="sm"
        debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" cookies="false">
```

where cookies="false" and it should be cookies="true".